# Error message when loading "caret" package with library in R

Tags: r, r-caret

I am trying to load "caret" package in R but it is showing the below error message. Please help me !

```
Loading required package: ggplot2
Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : 
  unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.3/library/Rcpp/libs/x64/Rcpp.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified procedure could not be found.

In addition: Warning messages:
1: package ‘caret’ was built under R version 3.2.5 
2: package ‘ggplot2’ was built under R version 3.5.1 
Error: package ‘ggplot2’ could not be loaded
```

Comment: Welcome to CV! Your question appears to be solely about programming and is therefore off-topic here. You could try asking your question on stackoverflow, but you will need to provide a minimum working example, such that others can reproduce your error.

Comment: Perhaps try installing (or re-installing) Rcpp package